# The Google Earth solution for panning in a 3D world

Tags: mathematics, camera, vector

About a year ago I made a solution for panning and zooming in a 3D world (Three.js) using a formula provided by @DMGregory. Here is the post: [How to panning camera on XZ axis with different angles](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/165862/how-to-panning-camera-on-xz-axis-with-different-angles)

The result is very cool, because it really feels like you are dragging the scene: 
https://codepen.io/josema/full/zMeNry

**The problem**

It turns out that I have to implement a following-object feature. In other words, I have to change the position of the camera to any part of the scene without losing the pan/zoom feature. And I think is not possible with this solution, because in this case the `camera.lookAt.y` changes when you pan. And it should be 0 to achieve what I want.

This is an example of what I would need, but the "responsive feeling" is not the same. https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_orbit.html (right click for panning). In this solution, we can easily say that the `camera.lookAt.y` is always 0.

The perfect solution is implemented by Google Earth:
https://earth.google.com/web/@40.40420135,-3.6986483,622.13605706a,960.94224964d,35y,-4.92354397h,63.56373285t,0r
Because it has the responsive feeling and the `camera.lookAt.y` is 0 when panning.

**Question**

Is it possible to implement something similar to Google Earth easily? If not how would you implement the https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_orbit.html?

Comment: So the difference which makes Google Earth better is that if you put your mouse on something and pan, it will end up on the same object once the panning in over. In the "Orbit Controls" example, the mouse would migrate away while panning. I think this is what makes it feel "responsive." Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct